# Simple WebGL program, draw points when mouse down, fail to work. help please

Tags: webgl

Here is the source code, pretty simple, but do not work.
// this is the html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            body { background: pink }
            canvas { background: orange }
        </style>
        <script src="utils.js"></script>
        <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;

            void main() {
                gl_PointSize = 10.0;
                gl_Position = aVertexPosition;
            }
        </script>
        <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            var canvas, gl, shaderProgram;
            window.onload = function() {
                initCanvasAndGL("canvas", canvas, gl);console.log(gl);
                initProgram(gl, shaderProgram);

                gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                var aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
                canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
                    onCanvasMouseDown(e, aVertexPosition, canvas, gl);
                }
            }

            function onCanvasMouseDown(e, aVertexPosition, canvas, gl) {
                var x = e.pageX;
                var y = e.pageY;
                x = (x - canvas.width / 2) / (canvas.width / 2);
                y = (canvas.height / 2 - y) / (canvas.height / 2);

                gl.vertexAttrib2f(aVertexPosition, x, y);
                gl.drawArray(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
            Canvas Not Supported! :(
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>

and this is the utils.js file

function initCanvasAndGL(canvasID, canvas, gl) {
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
    var names = [
        "webgl", "experimental-webgl",
        "webkit-3d", "moz-webgl"
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext(names[i]);console.log("i: " + i + "gl: " + gl);
        } catch(e) {}

        if(gl) {
            break; 
        }
    }

    if(!gl) {
        alert("WebGL is not available! :(");
    }
}

function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while(k) {
        if(k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }

        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

        var shader;
        if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.complieShader(shader);

        if(!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPLIE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

function initProgram(gl, shaderProgram) {
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders! :(");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
}
```

the console traces Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'VERTEX_SHADER' of undefined.So I add two console.log() in window.onload() function and initCanvasAndGL() function.And the result is:
i: 0gl: null utils.js:10
i: 1gl: [object WebGLRenderingContext] utils.js:10
undefined 
I really don't know why! who can help me? thanks.

Comment: 我知道了，在Javascript中所有的参数都是按值传递。简单类型和字符串是复制一个副本，对象是复制一个地址副本。所以gl =  canvas.getContext(...);实际上是改变副本的值，但没有改变全局变量gl的值，所以它还是Undefined。或者更形象的说，这个问题是因为混淆了变量的作用域。在函数中gl是一个形参，并不是全局变量gl。有两个办法可以解决这个问题：1）把initCanvasAndGL签名中的gl去掉。2）在initCanvasAndGL中使用this.gl而不是gl。显然第一种做法更好，因为第二种做法使得传入实参gl变得毫无意义。

Comment: 请用英文这样可以帮助到更多的人。Please use English so you have a chance to help people around the world.

Answer (score 1):

The code had multiple minor issues.

Please find a fixed version here:

[webgl_mousedown.html](http://pastebin.com/k70n0JGn)

[utils.js](http://pastebin.com/kEX7j4KR)